# CSS Not showing when pushed to website but shows on localhost - ReactJS / Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify

This is my website, it is not showing any of the styling but on my localhost it shows styling... any ideas? https://jaydenszekely.com/

All looks good to me but I must have missed something.

All my code is here :) https://github.com/deslabcreative/jaydenszekely

My CSS is imported in Layout.JS for anyone wondering :)

Nothing out of the ordinary in log that I notice :)

Please Help!

Comment: Check your CSS paths

Comment: @Torongo Yeah sure have, I havent changed the path since my last working build :)

Answer (score 1):

I took these steps and it fixed the build:

**Removed:**

- `.cache`
- `node_modules`
- commit the changes to repository

**Fixed:**

- added .gitignore (`.cache`, `node_modules`)
- replaced `PropTypes.file` with `PropTypes.string`
- git push all the fixes

Since there is a `yarn.lock`, Netlify will use yarn to install your dependencies, so no need for `node_modules`. The `.cache` is used by Gatsby, but will get created during the build, no need to commit it to the repository.

Comment: Thanks Heaps!  Could you share the repo with me with these fixes?  A bit confused with some parts :)